# Solving $\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}t}=kP\left(\frac{A-P}{A}\right)\left(\frac{P-m}{P}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, partial-fractions

I am having difficulties solving this differential equation for $P$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}t}=kP\left(\frac{A-P}{A}\right)\left(\frac{P-m}{P}\right)
\end{align*}
The context is a population model, where $A$ is the maximum sustainable population, $m$ is the minimum sustainable population and $k$ are constants.
The final answer I get is:
\begin{align*}
P=\frac{m-Abe^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}}{1-be^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}}
\end{align*}
where $b=e^c$.
This was achieved after the following:
My final integral after using partial fractions is:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{A-m}\left(\frac{1}{A-P}+\frac{1}{P-m}\right)\ \text{d}P&=\int\frac{k}{A}\ \text{d}t
\end{align*}
My final simplification process after the integration is:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\ln|P-m|-\ln|P-A|}{A-m}&=\frac{k}{A}t +c\\
\therefore\ln\left|\frac{P-m}{P-A}\right|&=\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt+c\\
\therefore\frac{P-m}{P-A}&=be^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}\;,\;b=e^c\\
\therefore P-m&=be^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}(P-A)\\
\therefore P-m&=Pbe^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}-Abe^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}\\
\therefore P-Pbe^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}&=-Abe^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}+m\\
\therefore P&=\frac{m-Abe^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}}{1-be^{\frac{(A-m)}{A}kt}}
\end{align*}
Is this correct, or have I made a mistake somewhere?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Should it be $\frac{P-m}{m}$ instead of $\frac{P-m}{P}$ in the problem?

Comment: No the question does say $\frac{P-m}{P}$

Comment: Then why not eliminate the $P$ in the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: Yes, my first step was $\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}t}=\frac{k}{A}(A-P)(P-m)$

Answer (score 1):

Good description of your process. I would like to know the initial value $P_0$. This is because it affects how one deals with the absolute value stuff. You just plain removed the absolute value sign, which for some initial values of $P$ can lead to error.

At a certain stage, you had $P-m=b\dots$. It should have been $P-m=\pm b\dots$.

Comment: $P$ is always positive because it is a population model, but there is no specific value for $P_0$ given.

Comment: Yes, $P$ is positive.  But how is $P_0$ related to $A$ and to $m$?  The sign depends on that.  If $P_0$ is unspecified, then we get slightly different possible forms for $P$.

Comment: I think $m<P<A$ would be true.

Comment: In principle not necessarily, since population can start below the minimum sustainable, or above the maximum. But if we assume that $m\lt P_0\lt A$, then $P$ will stay within those bounds. And if that is the case, then the equation you wrote is incorrect. It should have been $P-m$ is equal to the messy stuff in front times $A-P$, not $P-A$. Or else you can keep the $P-A$ but then you need a minus sign in front of the $b$.  For note that $P-A$ is *negative*. Or else you can choose to make $b$ negative, but that is in general not done.